# "order by" taking too much time in mysql

Tags: mysql

"order by" in query is taking to much time in MySQL. SHOW PROFILES shows that the time is taken by the sorting process. Is there any setting/workaround that will decrease the sorting time ?

Comment: How much time does it take, and how much time do you expect it to take?

Comment: wow so many answers and yet suggesting the same thing...

Comment: its taking 3 to 4 seconds and that is too much i think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have an index on the field that you're ordering by, add one:

"In some cases, MySQL can use an index to satisfy an ORDER BY clause without doing any extra sorting."

Edit: (From the [section on ORDER BY optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) in the MySQL documentation.)

Comment: i am using the index ,but still MySQL is not using file sort instead

Answer (score 5):

Adding appropriate indexes for the fields you're ordering by should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to increase the speed of returning sorted results by adding an index on the column(s) that you want your results ordered by.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD INDEX `indexname` (`columnname`);
```

Generally, indexname is the same as columnname.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the query is running slowly might be that the table is not indexed; if that is the case, create a suitable index.

Answer (score 0):

Can you let me know the output of the following 2 commands:
show create table tbl_name
explain "your select query"

MySQL will not use index if it thinks that almost all the rows needs to be examined unless there is a covering index. Since only one index per table is used, try to order by the column that is part of that index if it being used at all.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to indexing the column on which you want to run order by . you can run the sql
'`ALTER TABLE` yourTableName`ADD INDEX`ColumnName `(`ColumnName`);`'

i had the same problem, and overcame by this procedure.