# Performance difference in query between cmd and workbench mysql

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing

I have two questions:

1. As my title, which one is more efficient for running large query on large volume of data?

I've looked at MySQL doc which explains about workbench's performance in https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/performance/ however I cannot seem to find any resource that specifically talks about efficiency difference between running query on cmd and query on workbench.

2. How to optimize this query

   ```
   select
     r.user_id,
     k.id as kickscooter_id,
     st_astext(k.location) as location,
     k.created_at,
     k.serial_number,
     k_st.serial_number as states_serial_number,
     st_astext(k_st.gps) as gps_location,
     k_st.gps_updated_at,
     r.start_time,
     r.end_time
   from kickscooters k
   join rents r
     on k.id= r.kickscooter_id
   join kickscooter_states_190614 k_st
     on k.serial_number = k_st.serial_number
   order by r.rent_date
   limit 999;
   ```

I've learned that creating an index allows mysql to sort things quickly therefore I've added index by

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD INDEX `indexname` (`columnname`);
```

following answers from one of SO post ["order by" taking too much time in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130772/order-by-taking-too-much-time-in-mysql)

As suggested in comments I've executed

```
analyze <my query>
```

since my server is MariaDB.

which gave me ERROR CODE 2013: LOST connection to server during query.

When I ran

```
explain <my query>
```

It worked and outputs:

```
id    select_type   table   type          possible_keys                                                  
1     SIMPLE        k_st    ALL  kickscooter_states_190614_serial_number_date_index             
1     SIMPLE        k       ref  PRIMARY,kickscooters_serial_number_unique,kickscooters_serial_number_index     
1     SIMPLE        r        ref    rents_kickscooter_id_foreign    

-table continued
/       key                       key_len      ref                        rows         extra

        null                        null       null                      192818947      Using temporary; Using filesort
   kickscooters_serial_number_unique 27     kickgoing_db.k_st.serial_number 1   
    rents_kickscooter_id_foreign     4      kickgoing_db.k.id              143
```

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN <your select query here>` first and then post the result of this explain plan to the question.

Comment: Is the question "why is my query slow", or is the question "why is it slower on CMD than in workbench?". You seem to suggest they are both slow...

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I've ran it however it seems to take a while and gives me Error Code:2013: Lost connection

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I have two questions and yes I am suggesting both are taking a long time therefore I cannot measure which one is faster which is what I want to ask.

Comment: @makewhite Replace `JOIN` with `Straight_Join` and add a index on `rent_date` in `rents` table

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya rent_date in rents table is already set as an non-unique index with 724 cardinality

Comment: @makewhite please change the order of joins from table with low cardinality to high. And then specify `Straight_Join` so that optimizer does not change the join order

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks Madhur, could you recommend some resource that cover query optimizations that explains why one is faster than the other?

Comment: @makewhite Did the solution worked ? No official resource(s), but I find these two quite enlightening: mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql and http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Nope, I got rid of order by and limit, ordered joins from low to high cardinality however still taking a long time to finish.,

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the 3 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Explain plan, optimizer is not able to use any index for `ORDER BY rent`. So try the following:

1. Ensure that an index exists on the `rent_date` column of the `rents` table. This index will be used to optimize the `ORDER BY` clause. It can be a single column index, or a multi-column one (used in other scenarios). But, in case of multi-column one, you need to ensure that the `rent` column is the first column in the index order.
2. Ensure that an index exists on the `id` column of the `kickscooters` table. Details about single-column / multi-column index remains the same as in the point #1.
3. Ensure that an index exists on the `serial_number` column of the `kickscooter_states_190614` table. Details about single-column / multi-column index remains the same as in the point #1.

Now, after ensuring these indexes, try your original query. Most likely, optimizer should be able to optimize the Join Order. Besides, the above query, you can enforce join order by using [`STRAIGHT_JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/516720/2469308) optimizer hint. So, try the following query as well, and benchmark between the two of them:

```sql
select
  r.user_id,
  k.id as kickscooter_id,
  st_astext(k.location) as location,
  k.created_at,
  k.serial_number,
  k_st.serial_number as states_serial_number,
  st_astext(k_st.gps) as gps_location,
  k_st.gps_updated_at,
  r.start_time,
  r.end_time
from kickscooters k
straight_join rents r
  on k.id= r.kickscooter_id
straight_join kickscooter_states_190614 k_st
  on k.serial_number = k_st.serial_number
order by r.rent_date
limit 999;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. however when I run show index from table_name; for all the tables it satisfies all the conditions. rent_date in rents table is non_unique index however its sequence is 1 therefore satisfies your condition. Id in kickscooters table is a primary key, serial_number on kickscooter_states_190614 table is also non_unique with sequence of 1. Maybe it is because rent_date has cardinality of 724 which is very low compared to 2M rows?

Comment: @makewhite check your original query please and my answer again. I am not asking you to index on `rent_date`. but I am asking you to index on `rent` column (the column which is in your `ORDER BY` clause)

Comment: Sorry, actually it is supposed to be grouped by on rent_date I wrote it wrong in my query I will fix it.

Comment: @makewhite Please edit the question and add the result for `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for all the three tables; this will give an idea of indexes.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Please show us the `EXPLAIN` rather than talking about it.

Comment: @RickJames ?? I think you misunderstood. I am suggesting solution "based on the explain plan" in the original problem statement

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Alas `EXPLAIN` usually fails to tell you how to improve performance.  About all it does is provide statistics on what is going on _with the chosen execution plan_.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and `OPTIMIZER TRACE` provide some extra clues, but still not enough to know, for example, what index to add.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `WHERE` clause, but there is an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` involving `r`.  So, the Optimizer would like to *start* with `r`.  But...  There seems to be no index *starting* with `serial_number` for `k_st` (or there is a type or collation conflict), so it abandoned `r`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all 3 tables.